# what is the purpose of magic_quotes_gpc in php.ini file

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me what is the significance of the key magic_quotes_gpc in php.ini file.

Comment: That parameter doesn't exist, maybe you're referring to magic_quotes_gpc

Comment: I think the only purpose of the PHP Magic Quotes is to make us (sane programmers) crazy. Fortunately it's DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED in PHP 6. IMO this "feature" is in the top 5 of biggest mistakes in PHP.

Comment: @AlexV actually, there is noting that bad. Just a few lines of code let you forget this mess forever.

Comment: Yes I know but I would prefer that this feature would have never existed. How many times I entered a project where (bad) programmers didn't know it even existed (and the database data is saved with slashes and displayed with stripslashes)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's manual can tell you the significance:

> Sets the magic_quotes state for GPC
> (Get/Post/Cookie) operations. When
> magic_quotes are on, all '
> (single-quote), " (double quote), 
> (backslash) and NUL's are escaped with
> a backslash automatically.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime

Answer (score 1):

It was used to insert user submitted data directly into mysql queries without having to escape it.

It's now depreceated and should be leaved to 'Off' until PHP removes it, I prefer handling string escaping by mysqelf or by th DB abstraction layer than relying on php directive for this.

The point is that GET/POST/COOKIE vars are not only for DB storage, and I've seen too much emails or displayed text showing \' characters because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I spoils input data by adding some special characters to it.
Must be turned off